# SQL - How to find records in a time span

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got 2 tables, one with dates (let's call it Table1) - let's say with only 2 fields:

```
RecordID
DateTime
```

the other (Table2) is with info records and a datetime, like this:

```
RecordID
DateTime
Info1
Info2
```

I need somehow to get Table1.RecordID's where there are some entries between that record's DateTime and the next one.

Let's say we've got in Table1

```
1, 01/01/2010
2, 01/02/2010
3, 01/03/2010
4, 01/04/2010
```

and in Table2

```
10, 10/02/2010
11, 11/02/2010
12, 15/04/2010
```

So with these records I'd like to get the Records of Table1, where there are are entries in Table2 after the DateTime of a record till the next one (or if it's the last record in Table1, records in Table2 after that record in Table1).

Any ideas? :)

P.S - I use MSSQL

EDIT: little more info.

Thanks!

Comment: Are the RecordIDs in Table1 guaranteed to be in time order, with no gaps?

Comment: @Damien - yes. They are being inserted one after another with consequent dates.

Comment: @Dan - I tried to add some more explanation. Hope it'll help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the RecordIDs in table1 are sequential, without gaps, this makes our first task easier - we need to join two rows together from table1 to represent the timespans we're interested in:

```
Table1 t1a
    inner join
Table1 t1b
    on
        t1a.RecordID = t1b.RecordID - 1
```

except we need to deal with the last row which doesn't have another row to join to, so we need to make it a `left join` instead:

```
Table1 t1a
    left join
Table1 t1b
    on
        t1a.RecordID = t1b.RecordID - 1
```

Now we need to find out if there are any rows in Table2 which fit into this time period. There are two obvious ways to do this - with an `EXISTS` check in the where clause, or by an additional join and filtering using `DISTINCT`. Which one will work better depends on a number of factors, so would be worth profiling both:

```
SELECT t1a.RecordID
FROM
Table1 t1a
    left join
Table1 t1b
    on
        t1a.RecordID = t1b.RecordID - 1
where exists(select * from Table2 t2 where t2.DateTime >= t1a.DateTime and (t2.DateTime < t1b.DateTime or t1b.DateTime is null))
```

or:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1a.RecordID
FROM
Table1 t1a
    left join
Table1 t1b
    on
        t1a.RecordID = t1b.RecordID - 1
    inner join
Table2 t2
    on
        t2.DateTime >= t1a.DateTime and
        (t2.DateTime < t1b.DateTime or t1b.DateTime is null)
```

Obviously, the greater than and less than comparisons may need to be tweaked, depending on inclusive or exclusive lower and higher bounds on the timespan we've constructed.

---

If the RecordIDs aren't sequential, then we'll move to searching for the correct rows:

```
Table1 t1a
    left join
Table1 t1b
    on
        t1a.DateTime < t1b.DateTime
    left join
Table1 t1_nogap
    on
        t1a.DateTime < t1_nogap.DateTime and
        t1_nogap.DateTime < t1b.DateTime
```

We're now referencing Table1 a third time (t1_nogap), and trying to join a row that fits between the rows found by t1a and t1b.

So then we add an extra condition to the where clause, because we don't want to use timespans from t1a and t1b where we've found such a row:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1a.RecordID
FROM
Table1 t1a
    left join
Table1 t1b
    on
        t1a.DateTime < t1b.DateTime
    left join
Table1 t1_nogap
    on
        t1a.DateTime < t1_nogap.DateTime and
        t1_nogap.DateTime < t1b.DateTime
    inner join
Table2 t2
    on
        t2.DateTime >= t1a.DateTime and
        (t2.DateTime < t1b.DateTime or t1b.DateTime is null)
WHERE
    t1_nogap.RecordID is null
```

(and obviously, the other query can be similarly re-written)

Comment: Wow. That's really helpful of you! Thanks :) But I little misled you. Didn't get your question fully - There might be some gaps between the RecordID's, but they are sequential. This changes this thingy a little bit I guess :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.DateTime 
FROM Table1 T1, Table2 T2
WHERE T2.DateTime BETWEEN T1.DateTime AND (SELECT MIN(T3.DateTime) 
FROM Table1 T3 WHERE T3.ID > T1.ID)
UNION ALL
SELECT T2.ID, T2.DateTime
FROM Table2 T2
WHERE T2.ID > (SELECT MAX(T1.ID) FROM Table1)
```

Comment: `SELECT MIN(T3.DateTime)...` is going to be NULL for the last row of Table1.

Comment: I have added UNION ALL to achieve it.. Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this does what you want.

```
declare @T1 table (RecordID int, [DateTime] datetime)
declare @T2 table (RecordID int, [DateTime] datetime)

insert into @T1 values
(1, '2010-01-01'),
(2, '2010-02-01'),
(3, '2010-03-01'),
(4, '2010-04-01')

insert into @T2 values
(10, '2010-02-10'),
(11, '2010-02-11'),
(12, '2010-04-15')

select distinct T1_3.RecordID
from @T2 as T2
  inner join 
    (select
      T1_1.RecordID as RecordID,
      T1_1.[DateTime] as StartDate,
      (select top 1 T1_2.[DateTime]
       from @T1 as T1_2
       where T1_1.[DateTime] < T1_2.[DateTime]) as EndDate
    from @T1 as T1_1) as T1_3
  on T2.[DateTime] >= T1_3.StartDate and
     T2.[DateTime] < coalesce(T1_3.EndDate, '9999-12-31')
```